# Can't resolve ChildAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I copied the code below from another project into my project but it can't resolve symbol childAdapter .

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemList item = mItemList.get(position);
        String title = mCon.getString(R.string.title, item.getItemName(),mTotal+"");
        holder.tvTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(title));
        ChildAdapter adapter = new ChildAdapter(item.getImages(),mDisplay,mTotal);
        holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(new AsymmetricRecyclerViewAdapter<>(mCon,holder.recyclerView, adapter));
    }
```

Comment: ChildAdapter is a custom class. Just copy that class as well.

Comment: Thanks .. it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you just copied the code from another project, I believe that `ChildAdapter` is a custom class and thus it isn't available in your program by default. You should copy/import that class as well.